# How to add SSL support to web browser?

Tags: ssl, web-server, openssl, thttpd

Please suggest me how can I add SSL support to thttpd. Or if I can put it straight, how to make my web server have SSL support?

Comment: Don't use ancient unmaintained web servers?

Comment: Michael Hampton,May be its ancient but I could not shift to other web servers now! Is it possible to add SSL support to thttpd?

Comment: Fire up an instance of [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html).  It is a basic HTTPS to HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thttpd purposely does not support SSL as it is not intended for anything but the simplest embedded purposes. You could conceptually use some sort of SSL Reverse Proxy, but that really defeats the purpose of the software.

Comment: So... if I want to have my web server use SSL I need to look for alternatives! Thanks Chris!

Comment: Yes, either a full-function httpd, or a frontend reverse proxy. Or you could always add the SSL capability yourself if you know how to program.

Comment: Stunnel is a nice SSL proxy.